# Is unlimitedstorage available in Chrome Apps for Mobile?

Tags: storage, google-chrome-app, phonegap-build, indexeddb, cordova-chrome-app

Is [unlimitedstorage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#unlimited) available in [Chrome Apps for Mobile](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps)?

I am using indexedDB in a complex HTML5 mobile application for Android. The users have devices with low storage capabilities, so they get quota exceed exception frequently. I am trying Chrome Apps for Mobile, setting unlimitedstorage in manifest, but I still get quota exceed exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using temporary storage then temporary storage is allocated based on %, and each app can get a maximum of 20% of the allocated temporary storage shared pool.

Persistent storage give more storage limit than temporary storage, so you can consider using persistent storage, but of course it has pros and cons you have to weigh.

Read this [information from Chrome about offline storage limits](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#persistent)

Comment: Thank you hagrawal. I knew that information, however, it doesn't solve my problem. My question is specifically about unlimitedstorage option in Chrome Apps. I need this because Quota Storage API is not available for temporary storage (IndexedDB) in Chrome yet, and I need skip percentage limitations.